# Upload image and post data [React Native]

Tags: php, react-native, multipartform-data

[I am posting this on my web service.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6Uum.png)

What should I do with React native?
multipart \ form-data I have not tried it. Can both form-data and form-encoded-url be used?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to post in React-native, you can use formdata as below to upload image to webservice..

```
var formData  = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', {uri: link.uri, name: link.name, type: 'image/jpg'});

   fetch(url, {
       method: 'POST',
       headers:  {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Authorization': ' Token '+key,
    },
       body: formData
     })
```